# convert date to unixtime php

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have a form which posts date information month, day, yeah, hour, minute, am/pm. How do i encode/decode this to and from unixtime using php?

Comment: If I search SO with your title the first 7 or so hits contain the same answer you selected.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[mktime()](http://ie.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) - Get Unix timestamp for a date

```
echo mktime(23, 24, 0, 11, 3, 2009);
1257290640
```

To handle AM/PM just add 12 to hours if PM.

```
mktime($isAM ? $hrs : ($hrs + 12), $mins, $secs, $m, $d, $y);
```

Alternatively you could use strtotime():

[strtotime()](http://ie.php.net/strtotime) - Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp

```
echo strtotime("2009-11-03 11:24:00PM"); 
1257290640
```

Comment: using strtotime() is +1 for simplicity

Comment: When using strtotime don't forget about `...Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components...`

Comment: "To handle AM/PM just add 12 to hours if PM." This is tricky and will produce an error whenever the hour is 12. According to your statement, 10PM = (10 + 12) and that's true, but 12PM = (12 + 12) is wrong. Your statement works for all hours except for 12. In all logic, 12 PM should be 0 AM and 12 AM should be 0 PM. Or.. the difference between 10 apples and 12 apples is 2. The difference between 10 bananas and 12 bananas is 2. The difference between 10PM and 12PM = 14.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [mktime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) function

Comment: how would i handle the AM or PM?