# jQuery fullcalendar plugin not rendering the events retrieved from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I'm trying to add some events to fulllcalendar on my webpage. But it retrieves the values from the database but it doesn't show the results in calendar.

php

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `events` ORDER BY `id`";
$result = $mysqli->query($q) or die(mysql_error());
echo json_encode(mysqli_fetch_array($result));
```

js

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: true,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    events: "http://localhost/xxx/events.php",
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
        if (event.allDay === 'true') {
            event.allDay = true;
        } else {
            event.allDay = false;
        }
    },
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end, allDay) {
        var title = prompt('Event Title:');
        var url = prompt('Type Event url, if exits:');
        if (title) {
            var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/xxx/add_events.php',
                data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&url='+ url ,
                type: "POST",
                success: function(json) {
                    alert('Added Successfully');
                }
            });
            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end,
                    allDay: allDay
                },
                true // make the event "stick"
            );
        }
        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
    editable: true,
    eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
        var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/xxx/update_events.php',
            data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(json) {
                alert("Updated Successfully");
            }
        });
    },
    eventResize: function(event) {
        var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/xxx/update_events.php',
            data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(json) {
                alert("Updated Successfully");
            }
        });
```

json

```
{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"1","userid":"1","2":"sample","title":"sample","3":"2013-12-03 08:52:20","start":"2013-12-03 08:52:20","4":"2013-12-05 08:52:20","end":"2013-12-05 08:52:20","5":"0","allday":"0"}
```

Please anyone help me to solve this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your JSON, you problem is that the fullCalendar jQuery plugin requires that all datetime values be converted into a UNIX timestamp.

This might be of help [datetime - convert date to unixtime php - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670797/convert-date-to-unixtime-php)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Now I converted the `date` to `unixtimestamp` the `JSON` is `{"userid":"1","title":"sample","start":1386057140,"end":1386229940,"allday":"0"}` still it is not showing the event

Comment: Could be that the cases of some of your parameters do not match the [event object](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/). e.g. change "allday" to "allDay", and if you are to use it, do not use "0/1", but instead use true/false without doublequotes. "userid" is also not part of the event object, so that could be causing some problems as well. I hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry it is not working i have changed `allday` to `allDay` and `userid` to `id` and also i tried by removing `allDay` still it is not working

Comment: Justed looked at how I implemented this on my site. Try `$(document).ready(function() { $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ ... }); });` instead of `var calendar = ...`

Comment: If I remove the `var also the result is same. If I enter the `event objects` manually it works. Is that my json is in correct format???

Comment: Post your new JSON and let me see. Another possible error is with the event source. I wouldn't specify it as an "event" but specify an "eventSources" AJAX option: `eventSources: [
            {
                url: 'http://localhost/7starprojects/secure/events.php',
                type: 'GET',
                error: function () {
                    alert('Error grabbing calendar data!');
                }
            }
        ]`
And remove the "eventRender" option until you're able to display the events form your feed.

Comment: this is my new json `{"id":"1","title":"sample","allDay":true,"start":1386057140,"end":1386229940}`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42519/discussion-between-jranderson-and-james)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing I finally cracked the problem. For some reason full calender renders events if the events are supplied inside an array so it is like this.

```
Array[
   Jason Objects {},{},{} as many as you want
]
```

for me the below code works like a charm.

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'id' => $event->_id
        'title' => $event->eventName,
        'start' => date($event->start)
    )
);
return Response::json($data);
```

And BTW your first json object is correct just change userid to id and pass it through an array i guess it should work.

Hope this helps, Happy Coding :)