# php Convert datetime to unixtime with timezone

Tags: php, date

I have datetime `2017-10-11 09:40:42` of Asia/Karachi I want to convert it to unix timestamp.

Note: I have multiple records with different timezone eg: Australia/Sydney

I am failed to convert it from following code

```
function unixTimefromTime($thetime='now',$timezone){
    if(is_numeric($thetime)){
        $dt = new \DateTime('@'.$thetime);
        $dt->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone($timezone));
        return $dt->getTimestamp();
    } else {
        $date = new \DateTime($thetime, new \DateTimeZone($timezone));
        return $date->getTimestamp();
    }
}

unixTimefromTime('2017-10-11 09:40:42','Asia/Karachi');
```

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670797/convert-date-to-unixtime-php)

Comment: how its works with timezone.?

Comment: Can you please try this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668108/how-to-get-unix-timestamp-in-php-based-on-timezone

Comment: Also if you have done a search on google and here you would have found many answers. Even in PHP manual there are simple examples which you can work on [see the 3rd note](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
function DateTimeToUnixFromTimezone($dateNTime,$timezone){
    $date = new DateTime($dateNTime, new DateTimeZone($timezone));
    return $date->getTimestamp() + $date->getOffset();
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that if you add the offset to a timestamp, it's no longer unix time. Doing this is almost always a mistake. I can't think of a reason why anyone would want this.